# Streamlit app keep showing "Please wait..." and give error in terminal

Tags: python, web-applications, streamlit

The following error occurred in the terminal in Pycharm by running
streamlit run app.py

```
2022-08-19 20:50:02.531 Uncaught exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\project\movies-recommender-system\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\http1connection.py", line 276, in _read_message
    delegate.finish()
  File "e:\project\movies-recommender-system\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\routing.py", line 268, in finish
    self.delegate.finish()
  File "e:\project\movies-recommender-system\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 2322, in finish
    self.execute()
  File "e:\project\movies-recommender-system\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 2344, in execute
    self.handler = self.handler_class(
  File "e:\project\movies-recommender-system\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 224, in __init__
    super().__init__(application, request, **kwargs)
  File "e:\project\movies-recommender-system\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 215, in __init__
    super().__init__()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\typing.py", line 1083, in _no_init
    raise TypeError('Protocols cannot be instantiated`enter code here`')
TypeError: Protocols cannot be instantiated
```

Comment: Create another empty `try.py` file and write `st.write("Try")` and the run that file `streamlit run try.py` and if that work, then you will have to provide the code in your `app.py` and explane in your question what you did in terminal before running `app.py`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Uninstall `streamlit` and install the version `1.11.0`

Type into the terminal:

```
pip uninstall streamlit

pip install streamlit==1.11.0
```

Comment: Is there a fix now? the workaround version is quite old

Answer (score 0):

This problem shows up because of the streaming version. You can uninstall and reinstall the previous version.
Try this command:

```html
pip uninstall streamlit
pip install streamlit==1.11.0
```