# Streamlit - Protocols cannot be instantiated

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit

I tried running a simple

```py
import streamlit as st

st.write('Hello World')
```

It returns a `TypeError: Protocols cannot be instantiated.` Found a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73419067/streamlite-app-keep-showing-please-wait-and-give-error-in-terminal) mentioning installing a prior version, which resulted in the same error. The local app does launch, but sits on "Please wait..." screen.

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: same problem, got this after updating streamlit 1.12.0, running python 3.9.7

Comment: I am on 3.9.7 as well

Comment: Are you running the app with `streamlit run <name of your Python file>`?

Comment: Yes and I confirmed both the directory of the command line as well as the .py extention are correct and present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my python version to 3.10, which solved the issue. Apparently 3.9.7 causes this [issue](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/1332).

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a bug with Python 3.9.7 that developers weren’t previously running into because they weren’t using typing.Protocol until streamlit 1.12.0. You should update your python version

Answer (score 2):

try this "pip install --upgrade streamlit==1.0.0" Because sometime streamlit current version is not supported with your python version so degrade its version.

Comment: For me updating to python 3.10.0rc2 (the version I have from pyenv) didn't work, so I downgraded streamlit and it worked like a charm